# Custom Messages in Non-Windowed Classes - need a default handler?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, message, delphi-xe2, hwnd

With a class (TObject) I have :

```
private
  FHwnd : HWND;
  procedure HandleMyMessage(var Message : TMessage); message TH_MYMESSAGE;
```

where `TH_MYMESSAGE = WM_USER + 1`

In the class constructor:

```
FHwnd := AllocateHWND(HandleMyMessage);
```

The only object which receives a reference to `FHwnd` is a private custom TThread (created within this class) and the only message it posts is `TH_MYMESSAGE`.  My understanding is that the `message` directive in the procedure declaration restricts its handling to only `TH_MYMESSAGE`.

This was working fine in testing, but upon integration into a much larger application I am getting feedback that `HandleMyMessage` is firing for other messages as well (with obvious undesired results).

This was easily corrected by adding `if Message.Msg <> TH_MYMESSAGE then Exit;` in `HandleMyMessage`.  My question is :  Why is this happening?

My best guess is that `AllocateHWND` has made `HandleMyMessage` the equivalent of a `DefWndProc` despite it having the `message` directive.  Is there a correct way to implement this which I'm missing?

Comment: your guess is correct `HandleMyMessage` becomes `WndProc` of created non-visual window. so it recieves all messages; your solution to filter `Message.Msg` is correct too. `message` method modificator us used by Delphi for default handling `TObject.Dispatch` calls (in non-windowed classes)

Comment: @teran Assuming, then, that I did want a default `WndProc` for other messages would `HandleMyMessage` filter properly with the `message` directive if I had done `AllocateHWND` on some other general procedure?

Comment: @Ken No problem with WM_USER here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, yes of course. `AllocateHWnd` accepts a `TWndMethod` to act as the window procedure of the created window. The confusion, I guess, is caused by that the compiler accepts the `messsage` directive. Don't put it:

```
private
  FHwnd : HWND;
  procedure HandleMyMessage(var Message : TMessage);

..

procedure TMyClass.HandleMyMessage(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    TH_MYMESSAGE: //
  end;
  Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FHWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

---

**edit:** (Response to comment). To have the message handled on the class that created the utility window, you can route your message from the window AllocateHWnd creates to your class:

```
private
  FHwnd : HWND;
  procedure HandleMyMessage(var Message : TMessage);
  procedure THMyMessage(var Message: TMessage); message TH_MYMESSAGE;

..

procedure TMyClass.HandleMyMessage(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    TH_MYMESSAGE: Dispatch(Message);
  end;
  Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FHWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TMyClass.THMyMessage(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  //
end;
```

Comment: Does AllocateHwnd create a window that receives broadcasts? For something like this I'd be looking for a message only window, HWND_MESSAGE.

Comment: This makes sense.  The second part of the question :  could, in the same class, another procedure be defined which did use the `message` directive to steer specific messages away from the main handler?

Comment: @David - Sure, but using AllocateHWnd is so much easier. My system is full of 'TPUtilWindow's at any given time.

Comment: TObject.DefaultHandler will do the routing I guess but it's overkill unless you have a lot of messages.

Comment: No, I remembered wrong, Dispatch does the routing. @Sertac Why not call Dispatch always? Why the case? Pick up unhandled messages in DefaultHandler.

Comment: @David - Now I think understand your question. No, we're in the window procedure of the utility window, as far as the OS is concerned it is where messages that should be handled by *that window* is delivered. When we call 'Dispatch' we are calling a message handler of an entirely different class which may have a window of its own.

Comment: Hmm, if this class encapsulates a single  window, then I can't see any objection to calling Dispatch for all messages.

Comment: @David - Yes. I was thinking of wincontrols as an objection reason.

Comment: Hey, just a question, why does my WndProc (of a class) isn't working when i call AllocateHWnd from the Constrctor or AfterConstrction ? if i create it from a seperate method it works.

Comment: @user - Give it a shot posting a new question providing code sample that duplicates your problem.